# How can I turn this each method into a database query to speed it up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am currently using this to get all products and variants. I send this to the front end to be iterated over.

I would like to just have it hit the database and return results that I can iterate over without first having to iterate over each product.

```
Product.includes(:variants).each { |x| products_result << {id: x.id, title: x.title, sku: x.sku, image1_url: x.image1_url, option1: x.option1, option2: x.option2, category: x.category, variants: x.variants}}
```

The part I am struggling with, is that I don't know how to get a #variants method on the returned Products.

I am sending it to the frontend and need to be able to iterate over the variants. This is what I send to the frontend. The "imported_products" is not relevant to the question.

```
render json: { "products" => products_result, "imported_products" => imported_products }, status:200
```

Comment: Can you add your db/schema file showing the attributes of both tables, and the models to see their relationships?

Comment: You may use it as `x.variants.as_json`

Comment: Yon can also include with in as_json method like `products.as_json(id, title, includes: : variants`)

Comment: x.variants.as_json doesn't remove the .each method I am trying to get rid of.

Comment: This seemed to work. empr's comment led me to it Product.all.includes(:variants).as_json(:only => [ :id, :title, :sku, :image1_url, :option1, :option2, :category ], :include => :variants)